# Change innerHTML results based on selected "option"

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying to have it when I select an option from my dropdown menu it will update the results with the correct info from the data.json file. Right now it will return the stringified data from data[0], but I am wanting it to return based on the selected option id. So if the user selects "Sarah", being option id="4", I am wanting it to take the data from the 4th JSON object.

```html
<select id="options" onchange="myfunction()">
    <option ></option>
    <option id="0">Tyson</option>
    <option id="1">Jessica</option>
    <option id="2">Joshua</option>
    <option id="3">Jennifer</option>
    <option id="4">Sarah</option>
</select>
<br><br>

<div id="myData"></div>
```

```
function myfunction() {
    fetch('data.json')
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (data) {
            appendData(data);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log('error: ' + err);
        });
    function appendData(data) {
        var mainContainer = document.getElementById("myData");

        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data[0], null, 4);
        mainContainer.appendChild(div);
    }
}
```

```
[
  {
  "id" : 0,
  "first_name": "Tyson",
  "gender": "male",
  "isAlive": true,
  "married": true,
  "has_children": false,
  },

  {
  "id" : 1,
  "first_name": "Jessica",
  "gender": "female",
  "isAlive": true,
  "married": true,
  "has_children": false,
  },
  {
    "id" : 2,
    "first_name": "Joshua",
    "gender": "male",
    "isAlive": true,
    "married": true,
    "has_children": true,
  },

  {
    "id" : 3,
    "first_name": "Jennifer",
    "gender": "female",
    "isAlive": true,
    "married": true,
    "has_children": true,
 },
  {
    "id" : 4,
    "first_name": "Sarah",
    "gender": "female",
    "isAlive": true,
    "married": false,
    "has_children": false,
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, move `appendData` out of `myfunction`. It doesn't need to be nested.

Secondly, you need to capture the selected value of your dropdown within `myfunction`, and then filter your `data` collection based on that. Something like this, perhaps:

```
function myfunction() {
    var selectedId = document.getElementById("options").value; // e.g. "4" (string)
    fetch('data.json')
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (data) {
            // let's filter the data
            var person = data.filter(function(p) { return p.id == selectedId; });
            appendData(person);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log('error: ' + err);
        });
}
```

Lastly, you have to slightly adjust your `appendData` function to not try to index the `data` object anymore, because it's no longer an array:

```
function appendData(data) {
    var mainContainer = document.getElementById("myData");

    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
    mainContainer.appendChild(div);
}
```

One final suggestion would be to not put events in your HTML attributes. This is very antiquated. Instead, learn how to attach events to elements via the DOM using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).